# I also used symmetry in first and second cases. However, my calculations seem to be wrong. Why?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> There are $7$ people including A, B and C. In how many ways can they be arranged such that B is between A and C?

I broke this into cases

$$\_ B\space \_ \space  \_ \space  \_ \space \_ \space  \_ \space  $$

$2$ ways to put either A or C in first slot and one of them can be put in remaining 5 slots. Others can be permutated among themselves.

$$\binom{2}{1}\times 5\times 4! \times 2$$

$$\_ \space \_ B\space  \_ \space  \_ \space \_ \space  \_ \space  $$

$$2!\times 4\times 4! \times 2$$

$2!$ ways to put either A or C in first slot and one of them can be put in remaining 4 slots. Others can be permutated among themselves.

$$\_ \space \_ \space  \_ \space B  \_ \space \_ \space  \_ \space  $$

$$3\times 2 \times 3\times 4! $$

There are $3\times 2 $ ways to put A or C in 3 slots and one of them will seat in remaining 3 slots in $3$ ways.  Others can be permutated in $4!$

I also used symmetry in first and second cases. However, my calculations seem to be wrong. Why?

Comment: You should explain your reasoning, not just show a calculation.  That will make it easier to identify any errors you may have made.

Comment: For "$2!$ ways to put either A or C in first slot" read "$2\times2$ ways to put either A or C in one of the first $2$ slots"

Comment: Your first calculation seems to multiply by $2$ twice.  Once at the end and once in the binomial.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The first calculation is OK. He multiplies by 2 in the binomial because either A or C goes in the first slot; he multiplies by 2 at the end because B could go in the 2nd slot from the left or the 2nd from the right. The mistake is in the second calculation which is missing a factor of 2.

Comment: @bof I agree, the text doesn't mention this use of symmetry (until much later).  Therefore, there's either an extra $2$ in the first, or there's a missing factor in the second ...

Comment: @MichaelBurr My calculations are okay according to this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $7!$ ways to arrange seven people.  By symmetry, in one third of these arrangements, $B$ is between $A$ and $C$, so the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot 7!$$

**We correct your counts for the individual cases**

$B$ is in the second position:  There are two ways to choose whether $A$ or $C$ is to the left of $B$ and one way to place the chosen letter in that slot.  There are five ways to place the other letter to the right of $B$.  The remaining four letters can be arranged in the remaining four positions in $4!$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}4!$$
such arrangements.

$B$ is in the third position:  There are two ways to choose whether $A$ or $C$ is to the left of $B$.  Suppose it is $A$.  Then there are two ways to choose the position of $A$ and four ways to choose the position of $B$.  The remaining four letters can be placed in the remaining four slots in $4!$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}4!$$
such arrangements.

$B$ is in the fourth position:  There are two ways to choose whether $A$ or $C$ is to the left of $B$.  Suppose it is $A$.  Then there are three ways to choose the position of $A$ and three ways to choose the position of $C$.  The remaining four letters can be placed in the remaining four slots in $4!$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}4!$$
such arrangements.

By symmetry, the number of arrangements with $B$ in the fifth position is equal to the number of arrangements with $B$ in the third position and the number of arrangements with $B$ in the sixth position is equal to the number of arrangements with $B$ in the second position.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}4! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}4! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}4! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}4! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}4!$$

Comment: What's wrong with my calculations?

Comment: @Mr.Maxwell See my comment. Your 2nd calculation is off by a factor of 2; double that and you get a total of 1680 agreeing with Taussig's calculation.

Comment: Why do we multiply second case by 2?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking.  As I explained in my answer, we must choose whether $A$ or $C$ is to the left of $B$.  That accounts for one factor of $2$.  We must choose which of the two positions to the left of $B$ is filled by that letter, which accounts for another factor of $2$.  Also, in the final answer, the number of arrangements with $B$ in the fifth position is equal to the number of arrangements with $B$ in the third position.

Answer (score 1):

First choose 3 places where those 3 will be, that you can do on ${7\choose 3}$ ways.

On the middle of choosen places put $B$ and on other two put $A$ and $C$, that you can do on 2 way. Then permute all others on 4! way on remaining places.

So the answer is $${7\choose 3}\cdot 2\cdot 4!$$